# Object Array unique key validation using Superstruct

Tags: typescript

I want to validate Object Array that satisfies the uniqueness constraint by using Superstruct.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching but looks like it is not possible using super struct.

but maybe you can use an array type Set:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set